# Choosing a diff program for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff

I decided to try to contribute Firefox development, and they use Mercurial for source control. In the documentation about using Mercurial it was advised to choose a diff program and to do it before you start coding. They list a bunch of options, one of which appears to be the standard Unix/Linux diff program, which I'm somewhat familiar with via basic use.

The thing is, I hadn't realized that the diff program can even be an issue and I have a feeling that I won't know how to pick one until I pick the wrong one and get screwed by it somehow. So to skip this unnecessary hurdle, I'd like to ask what should I look at when choosing a diff program, and in what cases is the choice important (and in what way)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a program that can display differences and navigate between them quickly and easily.  If you're using it with a VCS, especially a DVCS like Mercurial, you'll want built-in merge support as well.

I'd recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).  It's intuitive and easy to use, they've got versions for Windows and Linux, and the Pro version (which doesn't cost all that much) has a very useful three-way merge feature.

Answer (score 3):

For me personally, I've used two different programs, [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html).  I believe they both run off the unix `diff`.  In my limited experience, you can't really go wrong with either of these diff programs as they have always produced identical results for me.  The main factor is personal preference.  The program `kdiff3` is more configurable, but I prefer `p4merge` when I am actually merging files (`kdiff3` requires an additional step to start merging).  `p4merge` has a little bit better looking interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/).  I *never* thought I'd move to a gui diff util until Meld came along.  It's simple, supports diffing many things (revisions, directories, files, etc), can do two-way or three-way diffs, and makes manually merging files a breeze.